# nightwatch selenium command "elements" returns error about first parameter, even when I pass in a css selector or xpath expression

Tags: selenium, command, element, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch with selenium for automation testing. I'm trying to use the selenium command 'elements' which takes a css selector or xpath as the first parameter, but keep getting the following error :

Error while running elements command: Please provide any of the following using strings as the first parameter: class name, css selector, id, name, link text, partial link text, tag name or xpath

My use is like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "My test" : function (browser) {
       ...  
       // want to get all the input elements from the document
       browser.elements('input','name', function(els){
       // of xpath like this
       browser.elements('//input','name', function(els){
       });
    }
```

}

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Ah I figured it out - the first param is a keyword which has to be one of these (from nightwatch selenium protocols.js)
 var check = /class name|css selector|id|name|link text|partial link text|tag name|xpath/gi;

So the command needs to look like this :
    browser.elements('tag name', 'input', function(el){
    })

Comment: Great call. Was stuck entering the value of these keywords wondering why the test was failing. Thank you.